# CORS Error in React 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, cors

Hello guys I got some CORS Issue now. so I found a few solution and I try that , but it still happened to me

api call

```
function signUpAPI(data) {
return axios.post('/api/signup', data);
```

}

setupProxy.js

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use(
        '/api',
        createProxyMiddleware({
            target: 'http://localhost:8080',
            changeOrigin: true,
        })
    );
};
```

this is error
[image]

Comment: its not your side problem i mean backend should allow to your front-end , and if backend allows you this error will be fix.   in  backend side we have some think like allow-origin and if you set it on * or your app address Ip its will be fixed

Comment: @RaminAzali thanks bro I try to do my best thanks for comment!

Answer (score 0):

Please add this line to sever of you:

```
  app.enableCors();
  await app.listen(3000);
```

You must open the server's CORS to be able to restApi, For more details please https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: I do not use node TT using spring boot now. anyway thanks bro !

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem before i added this to the sever side app  HttpServletResponse response:
`response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`
and `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")` on top your RestController class

Comment: is there any better way than that code bro?

Comment: not that i know of , normally for security reasons access is not allowed from other ports when you're using different server for the front so you have to manually allow it  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors